# Looking at a die

Tags: lateral-thinking

I have an opaque 6-sided die. Without using mirrors or any other optical aids, what is the greatest number of faces of the die that I am able to see at the same time?

Comment: You only need to see three sides to know where all six sides are, so you can comfortably look from afar at it. I can then see the other three sides in my imagination.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Due to the fact that the die is smaller than the distance between the eyes, if you hold it die very close to your face, it's possible to see 5 faces at the same time (all faces except the one opposite to you):

[image]

Comment: Technically, using some medical tools to bash one's face in, one might even be able to see all six sides :D

Comment: @dmg I'd consider it part of puzzle standard conditions that medical "enhancements" of involved creatures is not allowed. Otherwise I might as well just bash the teeth out of a certain fox in order to cross a river without it eating my chicken.

Comment: In my imagination, I can see them all ^^.

Comment: Did you try if it is possible to see all six faces if you hold a corner towards your face? It depends on the angle between your eyes and the opposite corner of the die. With a small die and a favourably shaped skull, it might be possible even without enhancements.

Comment: @JiK geometrically speaking, the die would have to be exactly between the two eyes. I don't think there's anybody whose skull would allow that, except using the kind of intervention dmg suggested

Comment: @w0lf If the die is exactly between the eyes, one can see each face in a rather good angle. Moving the die forward, the angle of the farthest sides will get smaller and smaller until the line of sight is perpendicular to the face, when the face is no more visible. The question is how far one can move the die before that happens.

Comment: Put the corner adjacent to faces 1, 2, and 3 between your eyes. Rotate the die so that the edge between faces 4 and 5 points to left eye and that the diagonal of the face 6 points to right eye. If the pupils are farther apart than those lines are, the left eye can see faces 1,4,5, and the right eye can see faces 2,3,6. I guess (but I'm not sure about this) that this requires that the angle "left pupil - opposite corner of the die - right pupil" is larger than 90 degrees, which still does sound implausible even with a tiny die.

Comment: @JiK I tried, it isn't very far from being possible, but it is definitely not possible with my head.

Comment: I don't consider this answer correct. A normal sighted human cannot focus anything closer than 7 cm, says Wikipedia. If it is close enough to the eyes for 5 faces to be exposed, the faces cannot be actually *seen*. For human visual perception, you need much more than just light entering through the pupil.

Comment: @rumtscho It doesn't need to be all that close, there is no theoretical limit to how far away the die can be while the eyes are still on the correct side of the faces. But you'll get a better angle by holding the die closer. I get the best view around 15 cm, I can focus, and I can tell all the pips apart.

Comment: I imagine if you orient it so one of the corners is nearest (and furthest) from your forehead and it's close enoug, you could see all 6 sides. Though I'm not sure if you could focus on it that close.

Comment: That picture gave me nightmares +1

Answer (score 21):

You didn't specify the material the die can be made of. Dice made of translucent plastic are common, and you can easily see all six sides.

[image]

Comment: Nice try, but I think I covered that with the word "normal".

Comment: I'm not sure that your usage of the word 'normal' implies that the die is opaque - usually it is taken to mean a die that is in the usual shape of a cube (if it has 6 sides).

Comment: I think commercially available in thousands of stores nationwide & online qualifies as 'normal'. https://www.google.com/search?q=red+translucent+dice&tbm=shop

Comment: In any case, it is a question about me and my die, my die is opaque.

Answer (score 4):

If your goal is to be able to see the most number of sides of a normal opaque die without any sort of aid, whatsoever, besides your own hands and eyes, then i'd say w0lf's answer is the best.

However if your goal is to see the most amount of sides of a normal opaque die without the aid of optical tricks but by utilising other tricks, then i'd suggest simply cutting off the faces of all six sides, thinly, line them up and you will be able to see them all, with an added bonus - the insides of the die! :O

Comment: But then it wouldn't be a normal die

Comment: @Richard, it would be a normal die, then you cut it up into 6 tinier normal dice. But the original die was normal. :D

Comment: But you killed the die!